# Getting logged userID without using asp.net identity

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We are working on a mvc project and we already did login register pages. But we didn't use asp.net identity framework. We are checking user datas from our database which is in sql server studio and paste user data when someone registers.

In our project it is kinda mentor-mentee match and mentor gives a project to his/her mentee. When we are creating a project we are using 2 tables from our database one is Mentee table and the other is Mentor table.

Creating new row in mentee table is easy but when a logged user creates a new task, we need his/her id to create a row in mentor table. Because if you are logged in and creating a task you are a mentor and we need to get the logged user id from our Users table.

I hope i make myself very clear and we need your help. If you need any code from our project i can edit post.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewLesson(DersAtamaModel model)
{
    using (DENEME_V2Entities db = new DENEME_V2Entities())
    {  
        LESSON lesson = new LESSON();
        lesson.LName = model.Project_Name;
        lesson.Intro = model.Intro;
        db.LESSONS.Add(lesson);
        db.SaveChanges();
        int Lesson_id = db.LESSONS.Where(x => x.LessonID == lesson.LessonID).FirstOrDefault().LessonID;
        TaskCreateModel tcmodel = new TaskCreateModel();
        tcmodel.Lesson_ID = Lesson_id;
        MENTEE mentee = new MENTEE();
        mentee.LessonID = Lesson_id;
        mentee.UserID = model.secilenKullanıcıId;
        mentee.Intro = "Intro";
        mentee.Statu = 0;
        db.MENTEEs.Add(mentee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        //MENTOR mentor = new MENTOR();
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            return RedirectToAction("CreateTasks", "Lesson",tcmodel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't you stored UserId in session when use logs in?

Comment: can you please explain how can we store userid in session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to store login id in Session when use logs in and then retrive the details when needed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserInfo user)
{
    Session["UserId"] = user.Id;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewLesson(DersAtamaModel model)
{
   int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
}
```

I have only provided code to set and get session. You should clear the session when user logs out using `Session.Abondon()` or `Session["UserId"] = null`